# Branching Apache Beam pipelines with loops

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to perform a de-noramlization operation, where I need to reorganize a table with the following logic:

```
| itemid | class | value |
+--------+-------+-------+
| 1      | A     | 0.2   |       | itemid | value A | value B | value C |
| 1      | B     | 10.3  |  ==>  +--------+---------+---------+---------+
| 2      | A     | 3.0   |  ==>  | 1      |   0.2   |  10.3   |         |
| 2      | B     | 0.2   |  ==>  | 2      |   3.0   |   0.2   |         |
| 3      | A     | 0.0   |       | 3      |   0.0   |   1.2   |   5.4   | 
| 3      | B     | 1.2   |  
| 3      | C     | 5.4   |
```

My approach has been to execute a for loop in order to filter by `class`, given that I know the list of classes a-priori and then to join the resulting pcollections.

The high-level code:

```py
CLASSES = ["A", "B", "C"]

tables = [  
    (
        data
        | "Filter by Language" >> beam.Filter(lambda elem: elem["class"]==c)
        | "Add id as key" >> beam.Map(lambda elem: (elem["itemid"], elem))
    )
    for cin CLASSES
]
```

and the join:

```py
_ = ( 
    tables
    | "Flatten" >> beam.Flatten()
    | "Join Collections" >> beam.GroupByKey()
    | "Remove key" >> beam.MapTuple(lambda _, val: val)
    | "Merge dicts" >> beam.ParDo(mergeDicts())
    | "Write to GCS" >> beam.io.WriteToText(output_file)
)
```

with (edit following Peter Kim's suggestion):

```py
class mergeDicts(beam.DoFn):
    process(self, elements):
        result = {}
        for dictionary in elements:
            if len(dictionary)>0:
                result["itemid"] = dictionary["itemid"]
                result["value {}".format(dictionary["class"])] = dictionary["value"]
        yield result
```

My issue here is that when the pipeline is executed within the Apache Beam compute engine, I obtain identical pcollections filtered by the last element of the list, which in this case is C.

[ADDED] It looks like the Apache Beam engine takes the iterating variable in its final state, which means the last element of the iterated list, for all the invoked branches.

I am obviously following the wrong approach, but which should be the best way to perform this operation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're running into is the surprising gotcha with respect to [closures, loops, and Python scoping](https://eev.ee/blog/2011/04/24/gotcha-python-scoping-closures/). You can get around this by assigning the variable rather than pulling it from the closure. E.g.

```
tables = [  
    (
        data
        # Pass it as a side input to Filter.
        | "Filter by Language" >> beam.Filter(lambda elem, cls: elem["class"], c)
        | "Add id as key" >> beam.Map(lambda elem: (elem["itemid"], elem))
    )
    for c in CLASSES
]
```

or

```
tables = [  
    (
        data
        # Explicitly capture it as a default value in the lambda.
        | "Filter by Language" >> beam.Filter(lambda elem, cls=c: elem["class"])
        | "Add id as key" >> beam.Map(lambda elem: (elem["itemid"], elem))
    )
    for c in CLASSES
]
```

Partition works well here too, both in avoiding this pitfall and in expressing your intent.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the resulting table you showed, I assume you want your output to look like this:

```
{'itemid': '1', 'value B': 10.3, 'value A': 0.2}
{'itemid': '2', 'value B': 0.2, 'value A': 3.0}
{'itemid': '3', 'value B': 1.2, 'value A': 0.0, 'value C': 5.4}
```

Your mergeDicts was overwriting values because dictionaries can only hold one value per key. Update mergeDicts to something like this to specify the keys:

```
class mergeDicts(beam.DoFn):
    process(self, elements):
        result = {}
        for dictionary in elements:
            if len(dictionary)>0:
                result["itemid"] = dictionary["itemid"]
                result["value {}".format(dictionary["class"])] = dictionary["value"]
        yield result
```

Comment: Thank you, I made this up as a dummy example and I forgot to include the fact that I renamed the fields of the dictionaries before the join. 
I am sorry for the mistake, however, the problem is that the obtained dictionaries are all identical even before the join. I am editing the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Tonca No worries. The for-loop should definitely work. In fact, the result I showed in my answer was generated by your code, with the only changes of mergeDicts and `for class in CLASSES` (since `class` is a reserved keyword). I used apache-beam 2.23. How did you verify that the obtained dicts are all identical?

Comment: Thanks Peter. Actually my original use case is more complicated (more fields and more joins with other dataframes), but I was sure that the operation causing the rows being all identical was the one that I described in the question. Apparently it is not.
I am performing many checks with slightly different operations (like in the case of the class `apache_beam.Partition`) that give good results in some cases and wrong in other, but I couldn't sort out which is the cause of the issue.

Comment: @Tonca I see. I can't tell what could've be done, but I'm glad you figured out that `partition` serves the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

*I am posting here a solution that I found by myself, but I am not checking it as the correct answer, because I would like to understand better the execution logic of the Beam engine.*

Instead of filtering the table by the items in a loop, in order to obtain separate pcollections on a condition, I used the [`beam.Partition`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/partition/) class. By applying the code sample in the documentation directly, I partitioned the pcollection into multiple tables, ready to be joined.

This way the issue is avoided, however it is not clear to me why the for loop doesn't work as I expected.